# How to set the same value for two inputs in form_for rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I need to set same value for two inputs in form_for in rails view

```
         .form-box
          = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(:user), html: { class: "guest-form", autocomplete: "off" }) do |f|

            = f.text_field :username, placeholder: "Username", class: "input"
            = f.password_field :password, class: "input", style: 'visibility: hidden'
            = f.submit "Enter", class: "signup"
```

I need to set :password same value as :username. Is it possible to do it without using jquery or overriding devise? for example with value: attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your User model you can do:

```
class User
  ...
  before_validation :init_password, on: :create

  private

    def init_password
      self.password = username
    end
end
```

And remove the field of the form.

This must do the trick.

Comment: You're welcome. Please, select if the answer is right (the best way to say thank you).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of an input by simply passing `value` attribute:

```
     .form-box
      = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(:user), html: { class: "guest-form", autocomplete: "off" }) do |f|

        = f.text_field :username, placeholder: "Username", class: "input"
        = f.password_field :password, class: "input", style: 'visibility: hidden', value: f.object.username
        = f.submit "Enter", class: "signup"
```

Comment: it doesn't work because after submiting password_field is blank.
I am getting validation error

Comment: I'm guessing you do not need the `f.password_field` at all. This is the controller job in this case (to set user default password).

Comment: I am doing it with devise. And I am lookngig way to not overriding devise's controlers

Comment: Well, Ok then, it's your decistion. Use `f.hidden_field` instead of `f.password_field`, e.g: `f.hidden_field :password, value: f.object.username`. However, it will not probably change anything, because it is just a better way of having hidden `f.password_field`. The rest in within your controller.